# Why don’t you vs Why won't you

Tags: phrase-choice

[I put in some edits]

- Son, switch the lights off. The movie's about to start.
- [edit] Why don't you do it, dad? (or Why won't you do it dad?) [edit]
- Dad answers: Because I'm scared of darkness. And you're the closest to the switch. [edit]

When I wrote this dialog I didn't even consider won't. But then a doubt came up that maybe it can work too. I still prefer the first choice but can't explain why. Can you clarify? And does the mood of Joe matter, i.e. whether he's complaining or just asking in a chill way and not minding the dad's request.

Edit: my understanding at the moment is that

1. "Why don't you do it, dad?" implies a more neutral tone, simply asking for the reason why the dad

And 2. "Why won't you do it, dad?"
carries a more assertive or frustrated tone, suggesting a bit of impatience or annoyance with the dad's reluctance

Comment: Please use the "Edit" button to add more to show that you understand the difference in meaning between "don't" and "won't"; if not, that's what we should talk about. Note, this site doesn't give writing advice so we can't tell you which meaning to choose, but asking about which usage is idiomatic for a particular situation is fine.

Comment: Who is afraid of the dark here, the father or the son?

Comment: Disregard the DV on mine.

Comment: Voting to close until edited.

Comment: @AndyBonner He did put it into a dialogue; He has shown effort. I don't think this merits being closed.

Comment: @Lambie Actually, my concern wasn't "lack of effort" (I'm generally ambivalent about such a "work ethic" requirement anyway), just that the question isn't clear enough (to me, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

The literal meaning of "Why don't you..." is asking why someone does not do something on a regular ongoing basis. "I do this" means they do the thing repeatedly or continuously, up to and including the present.

> Why don't you go to the gym?
>
> I hurt my back and can't exercise.

**However there is a much more common meaning which is as an invitation or suggestion.**

> Why don't you go, Dad?

Is usually taken as a suggestion that Dad goes - often instead of someone else.

> I can't go to pick up the food order. Why don't you go, Dad?

> I can't come to visit you that day. Why don't you visit me instead?

"Why won't you..." implies that the person has made a choice not to do something, and asks the reason for that choice.

> Why won't you visit your brother?
>
> We had a disagreement many years ago.

Comment: Why won't you is also not a way to begin a conversation.

Answer (score 0):

"Don't" is more definitive, there is an actual obstacle, "won't" is more related to reasons that are less clear, such as feelings.  In this case there is presumably no obvious reason, (his leg isn't broken or anything like that), so "won't" would be more correct.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't  you go to Dad? [to complain, suggestion]

Why won't you go to Dad? implies the person didn't want to go to Dad before and the other person thinks he should.

John: I really want to complain about this. But I don't think I should go to Dad.
Alan: Why won't you go to him? He would help you.

i.e. why don't you have the intention of going to him?

Why don't you [predicate] **can** be a conversation starter.
Why won't you [predicate] cannot. It implies some previous interaction.

Answer (score 0):

- Why won't you = *why **will** you not*
  "Will" suggests of a *choice* whether to perform the action or not.
- Why don't you = *why **do** you not*
  "Do" focuses on whether the action happens or not.

So, "*why won't you go?*" asks why a person is choosing not to go (or perhaps choosing/insisting on staying), whereas "*why don't you go?*" invites reasons why they haven't.

Comment: Why won't you go asks why a person is choosing not to go, so that has already been established. You can start a conversation with Why don't you x? You don't generally start one with Why won't you x?

Comment: @lambie erm, nobody is doing that. The question is what *would* be the difference.

Comment: Oops, correction: ask //Why won't you believe me? [we've been talking].

Answer (score 0):

Side note: What is the function of "dad" in your example? Do you  mean, "Why don't you go, dad?" making "dad" a reference to the person you are addressing? If so, you need the comma. Or do you mean, "Why don't you go to dad?" or "Why don't you go ask dad?" If so, you've left out a word. I'll assume you mean, "Why don't/won't you go, dad?"

"Won't" is short for "will not", and it means that the person chooses not to do it. They could but they refuse. "Don't" is short for "do not" or "did not" and means that the person did not do it with no inherent indication of why not.

If I say, "Bob didn't go", it could be that he was perfectly able to go but refused. Or it could be that something prevented him from going, perhaps something totally outside his control. We can't say without more information.

So "don't" is more general than "won't". "Don't" could mean deliberate refusal, or it could mean lots of other things.

In this case, I think "don't" is more appropriate. The person asking doesn't know why the person asked did not do it. It could be that he was able but refused. Or it could be that something prevented him. If he knew why, it might not be necessary to ask the question.